# Different directories (one created in Jupyternotebook, one created on desktop) of the same csv file produce different results

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, sys

I'm new to python using sys module. My python version is Python 3.9. I'm using sys module to compute cases of covid in different regions of the US and it needs 5 arguments in cmd. When the directory is created in jupyternotebook's folders online, the program runs fine. BUT when the directory is created locally on desktop, the program cannot produce the results. Here are the succeeded one and the failed one:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E28a8.png)

5 arguments are: program name(.py file), start date, end date, covid cases directory, state to region directory.

Different directories of the same csv file produce different results. I'm really confused.

Comment: My guess would be that those files don't actually exist.  BTW, please don't post screenshots of your code.  Instead, cut-and-paste the text.

Comment: Are you sure those are the same csv file? Are the formats identical? You said one was created somewhere else, right? The notebook online is using Linux (more than likely), and you're on Windows. There are differences in how those operating systems create CSV files! Also, posting the code of the Python file around where the error is occurring would help.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I will do the cut-and-paste work next time! @Tim Roberts

Comment: They are the same csv file, and the formats are identical. One is on the desktop and the other was the same one uploaded to Jupyternotebook. I think you might be right about the operating system. I will try to write a local .py file to figure out what's going on. @DanielSchroederDev

Comment: If you post the relevant portion of the Python file in your original question, it may help as well.

Comment: I have posted new question which best represents this problem. It turns out to be one file is not read because of different form of datetime. Thanks for your help. @DanielSchroederDev

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.